# JavaScript on MouseOver change BODY style. Reverse on MouseOut

Tags: javascript, css, onmouseover, onmouseout, document-body

I wish to use JavaScript to apply the `style` given below to the `body` of the HTML or another `div` on `mouseover`. And reverse on `mouseout`. Both with a fade if possible?

**Style:**

```
.box-style_img2 {
    background-image: url(img.png);
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #00a0b0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.
P.S. Just beginning to learn Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to do things in CSS if you can avoid Javascript

Try using `:hover` property of css. For animation use `transition` property

```
<div class="box-style_img2">    
</div>

.box-style_img2 {
    background-size: auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #00a0b0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.box-style_img2:hover {
    background-size: auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Also you can check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9JJnp/) fiddle

Comment: I want on mouse over a div, to change the body's style.

Answer (score 0):

```
function on_mouseover(){
document.body.className += "your-class-to be applied";//for body
or
document.getElementById("div-id").className ="your-class-to be applied"
}

function on_mouseout(){
document.body.className += "your-initial-css-class";//for body
or
document.getElementById("div-id").className ="your-initial-css-class";
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div id="div-id" onmouseover="on_mouseover()" onmouseout="on_mouseout()"></div>
```

Or you can use addEventListener if you dont want to write javascript inline

```
document.getElementById('your-id').addEventListener("mouseover",on_mouseover);
document.getElementById('your-id').addEventListener("mouseout",on_mouseout);
```

Note:This task can also be done using plain css also.

```
.your-class{
//properties to be applied on mouseout
}
.your-class:hover{
//properties to be applied on mouseover
}
```

Comment: The style to be applied, will change for every DIV, so I can't use a global style in this case. How can I achieve this within the DIV: onmouseover="on_mouseover()" onmouseout="on_mouseout()" ?

Comment: I see. But I will need to place the "function" in the head section right? How can I get the same function, inside the DIV, in the body of the document?

Comment: boris,i think its time to grab a good book on javascript,you will have thousands of questions in your mind..because javascript is literally a very vast language  and there is a lot off stuff to learn..

Comment: regarding your question..javascript code is written inside <script> tag</script>..this script tag is to placed inside the head section(if you want to load your js before all the dom elements load) or before the <body> tag end(if you want your js to load after dom elements have loaded)..I hope I am clear.Please accept the answer if you think its worthy